# Serving CSS files singularly rather than batched

Tags: css, elixir, phoenix-framework

In phoenix is there a good way to serve the css file singularly rather than batched together. Because I am having to send down a bunch of css cruft from other pages for the one page that I am trying to view. Not to mention that this css batching can lead to conflicting styles if not careful.

Static Folder Directory Structure:

```
static
- css
-- list.css
-- detail.css
```

After running "mix phoenix.server" I inspect the resources getting delivered for my list.html page and see an "app.css" file being delivered. This css file contains the styles from both the list.css and the detail.css file combined. I would like to find a way such that only the list.css styles get delivered for the list.html page. As I am now sending down more data than is necessary for the list.html page.

Comment: Could you please expand on what you're trying to achieve? Maybe a concrete example or code snippet would help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by putting your CSS files directly in the `priv/static/css` folder, not inside the `web/static/` directory.

This way your files are served on by one and need to be called from your HTML code one by one, as you do with raw HTML. Be aware that they we'll be served as they are without any Brunch optimization unless you configure Brunch (only if you want).